# Does VB6 have linq expressions?

Tags: vb6, unmanaged

I'm arguing with one guy about linq in visual basic.He shows linq expressions in vb,but I can't be sure if it's managed or unmanaged(vb6),because I've never used any of them.

Does VB6 have linq expressions?

Comment: I would stick with calling it vb6 and not unmanaged vb as that is a very misleading term.

Comment: Also, be aware that there are more differences between VB6 and VB.Net than one is unmanaged and one is managed. The differences are many and varied, to the extent - that while they might be superficially similar - they are VERY different languages.

Comment: VB6 does not have linq . . . or class inheritance, Garbage collection, generics, partial classes, strict typing, xcopy deployment, nor the ability to target web sites, web services, windows services, console applications . . . to mention but a few of the many MANY things that VB6 does not have, and one more thing it NEVER had? My love and affection, I worked with it for years, and I never liked it.

Comment: Brian, VB6 actually does have garbage collection (always had it) and xcopy deployment with reg-free com ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx ). You can also do windows services with a hack ( http://vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=92 )

Comment: @AngryHacker: Reference counting is NOT Garbage Collection, and - while you could hack VB6 to do lots of things - when it comes to reliable, deployable, testable and maintainable software, hacks are not acceptable. All the reference counting and hacks in the world won't change the fact that VB6 was a complete pain in the @rse, a shattered landscape of dead-ends and razor sharp edge cases. I'm glad it's dead, I'm glad it's buried, and I'm glad I can say "never again"

Comment: @Binary Worrier: FWIW Wikipedia lists reference counting as one form of garbage collection. Anyway, if you two want to continue this discussion, can I suggest you move to your blogs or a newsgroup.

Comment: @Binary Worm - My first reaction is your posts should be tagged as "Hate Speech" and I even sense you'd agree!  Suck it.

Comment: @MarkJ: I was actually unaware of that, so I stand corrected, thanks. @Karly Pretension: I dislike Vb6 intently, but reserve my hate for broccoli. And I've to suck what exactly? P.S. You appear to have misspelled my name :)

Comment: @Karl E, MarkJ et al. Seriously guys, I apologise for any offense I've caused by airing my Vb6 rant publicly. Vb6 has a large user group and fan base, and I don't want to offend anyone. Yes I dislike Vb6, I also dislike Heavy Metal, it doesn't mean I think there's anything wrong with folks that like either (and/or both). See you around guys :)

Comment: @Binary Worrier.  #1. Don't want to get into the flamewar, but as MarkJ pointed out, Ref counting is GC.  The hack was microsoft's approved way of turning regular EXEs into services back then.  VB6 was great for its time and is still widely used.

Comment: @AngryHacker: Yes, you are correct, I was wrong, about everything. I'm a bad person and shall go away and punish myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Basic 6 does not have LINQ extensions.

Comment: +1, correct. Although one of Microsoft's sample videos on NET/COM Interop has a VB6 exe calling a .NET component that uses LINQ. But the answer to the original question is still "NO". http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/funkyonex/Tips-and-Tricks-with-the-Interop-Forms-Toolkit/

Answer (score 5):

VB6 is not related to VB.NET. It's a different language and platform. The two are related in the sense that C and C++ are related.

In particular, VB6 is not an unmanaged form of VB.NET.

LINQ is part of the .NET Framework. VB6 was released in 1998. .NET was released in 2002.

The VB6 IDE is unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

Linq is fairly new (Released 2007). Its not supported by VB6 which was released about 1998

Answer (score 1):

With version 7 Visual Basic took the step into .NET with managed code and real object orientation, leaving the old unmanaged platform behind. (Well, it was never called unmanaged, as there was no managed code...) Version 9 was released a while a go including LINQ support.

So, no VB 6 doesn't support LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can use LINQ and Lambda expressions in VB 6 is to use COM Interop. The performance is still Okay regardless of the time that you need to consider for proxy and translators.

For scenarios that you need to use LINQ and [Parallel LINQ(PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx) in your VB 6 code, the best solution is to use [COM Callable Wrapper(CCW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx). To learn more, you can read [how to expose a .NET COM to a COM client such as VB 6](http://blog.csharplearners.com/2012/02/06/visual-basic-6-linq/).

Comment: can you quantify or qualify what you mean by performance still being okay?